# why i'm Showing this error when i fetch Market items?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, tokens, dapps

function :

```
  function fetchMarketItems () public view returns(MarketItem[] memory) {
        
          uint itemCount = _tokenIds.current();
        
          uint unsoldItemCount = _tokenIds.current - _tokensold.current();
          uint currentIndex = 0; }
```

error :

```
TypeError: Operator - not compatible with types function (struct Counters.Counter storage pointer) view returns (uint256) and uint256
--> testit.sol:3113:34:
|
3113 | uint unsoldItemCount = _tokenIds.current - _tokensold.current();

| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

error 2 :

```
TypeError: Type function (struct Counters.Counter storage pointer) view returns (uint256) is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256.
--> testit.sol:3113:11:
|
3113 | uint unsoldItemCount = _tokenIds.current - _tokensold.current();
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: one problem is there is a return type defined in the function declaration but there is no implicit or explicit return in your function

Comment: i will return items latr , but error is here not linked to return type

Comment: Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
  Counters.Counter private  _tokensold;

Comment: can you change `_tokenIds.current` to `_tokenIds.current()`  (parentheses) on the end, and check `_tokensold` name consistent throughout. Generally you'd go for a capital S i.e. `_tokenSold`

Comment: if the answer helped you please upvote and accept

Answer (score 0):

The errors are due to the missing parentheses on

```
 _tokenIds.current
```

vs.

```
_tokenIds.current()
```